# R ggplot2 number of rows of the same values in a column

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm new to R and plotting in R. This might be a very simple question but here it is,

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
a    b    c    d

1    5    6    7
2    3    5    7
1    4    6    2
2    3    5    NA
1    4    4    2
2    2    4    2
1    2    5    1
2    3    4    NA
```

Here a, b, c, d are column names. I want to plot a bar chart that has values in column d on the x axis, and the number of rows with that value on y axis. So 7 has 2 rows, 1 has 1 and 2 has 3. It's not important to include missing values in between(3, 4, 5, 6).

So the result would be something like a histogram. I know I can do counting on column d and then do the plotting but I feel there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: `ggplot(dd, aes(factor(d))) + geom_bar(stat="bin")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach--if I understand your question, columns A, B, and C are immaterial to what you are doing, which is plotting frequencies of column D.
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

##get frequencies of col d
test.summary<-table(test$d)

## re-shape the data 
test.summary.m<-melt(test.summary)
ggplot(test.summary.m,aes(x=as.factor(Var.1),y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Comment: @MrFlick wins here :)

Comment: Thanks! This is what i want. Are names like 'test.summary.m' common practice in R?

Comment: Not sure what is common. Dots are not illegal in R, but you may want to skip them anyway. Probably bad practice.

Comment: @Gnijuohz "The preferred form for variable names is all lower case letters and words separated with dots (variable.name), but variableName is also accepted" (https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml#identifiers)

Comment: @beetroot Thanks so much for the link! That was exactly what I was asking for ;)